# PHP multiple file upload script not working

Tags: php, file-upload

this the html markup for multiple upload..i want to perform validation to it..
1)check if the file is 5 mb
2)check if it is jpg,gif only image file

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple">
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

here is the php code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){        
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name)
    {           
                 if($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], "images/{$name}")){

            $uploaded[] = $name;
                 }
    }       
    print_r($uploaded);     
}
```

right now its just uploading the file without any validation...i cant figure out wat to do to check the size and check if its image type only.....please php experts help me out

when i try to use this it directyl uploads

```
  if($_FILES['file']['size'][$key] > 5000){
                     echo 'file must be under 5 mb';
                   }else{
                     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], "images/{$name}")
```

}

Comment: Hint: Use print_r() or var_dump() on $_FILES to understand more of what it contains.

Comment: @..... What should be the good idea? uploading all valid file and throw error for not valid file at last OR throwing error directly when one invalid file found?

Comment: use xDebug to debug your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(...) {
   $fileType = explode(".", $name);
   $fileType = strtolower("." . $fileType[count($fileType)-1]);

   if(!in_array($fileType, array('.gif','.jpg','.jpeg')))
       echo 'Incorrect file type';
   if($_FILES['file']['size'][$key] > 5000)
       echo 'Maximum alowed size is 5MB';

}
```

Comment: what if the image extension is of uppercase? like Jpg?

Comment: this is what `strtolower()` is doing.. it transform letters from upcase to downcase..

Comment: works fine :D thnx :D...but the the problem is if i upload a larger file it doesnt show maximum file allowed error :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php for checking the type of an image

The size can be found in the $_FILES array (under size), e.g. $_FILES['file']['size'][$key]

Answer (score 0):

It is uploading file because you have written code for uploading in this

```
if($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], "images/{$name}"))
```

Comment: ya but actully i want the script to perform validation

Comment: which validation you want to do with the image??

Comment: that validation @Matai Mihai has answered. Is it working or not for you??

Comment: no its not working whn i try uploading with it it shows max file size allowed is 5 mb but iused 1mb file...

Comment: change `5000` to `5000000`. actually `5000` is 5kb because of this it is showing `max file size allowed is 5 mb`..